# Android - Getting Current Audio/Video Output

Tags: android, audio, video

Is there a some possibility to get current Audio/Video output mode on Android(like HDMI,SPDIF etc) using Android SDK?

Android >4.0

Comment: On Jellybean and later you can use `getSelectedRoute(ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO)` (or `ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO`) on a [`MediaRouter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter.html) object. The `RouteInfo` object it returns has a `getName` method.

Comment: Thanks, use this as an answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with API level 16 (Jellybean) there's the [`MediaRouter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter.html) API which allows you to get some information about the current audio/video routing.
To get routing info you'd use the `getSelectedRoute` method, with the `ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO` or `ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO` flag. This gives you a `RouteInfo` object, through which you can get the name of the route using the `getName` method.

For example:

```
MediaRouter mr = (MediaRouter)getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
RouteInfo ri = mr.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO);
if ("HDMI".equals(ri.getName().toString()) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I could possibly combine this with MediaRouter support APIs? Specifically, I want to be able to use the same APIs that I use for Chromecast as the ones I use for Bluetooth device detection/selection.  Google Music does this somehow, but I'm having a hard time finding out how they did this.