# Get current audio output Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager

I want to get current playing audio device (like phone, wired headphones or bluetooth device). Do you know how to get?
My code:

```
val manager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
return if (manager.isBluetoothScoOn) "Bluetooth"
else if (!manager.isBluetoothScoOn && !manager.isSpeakerphoneOn) "Wired"
else "Phone"
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the current code? Note that in the case of media playback over bluetooth, A2DP would probably be used rather than SCO.

Comment: Also, assuming that your minSdkVersion is at least 16, you may want to consider using `MediaRouter`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054711/android-getting-current-audio-video-output

Comment: I get only Wired output with this code

Comment: I am also struggling to get current audio device if there is something like that..